# Wordpress menu ancestor not given ancestor class

Tags: wordpress

Please take a look at this: http://halo.meredevelopment.co.uk/2011/11/creative-and-digital-media-apprenticeship/

The menu item 'Halo Home' has the classes 'current-post-ancestor' and 'current-menu-parent' as expected. Any idea why 'Halo News' item above it doesn't have the ancestor class?

If you look at this is does: http://halo.meredevelopment.co.uk/category/halo-home/

I believe that all ancestors in menus should be given either a parent or ancestor class depending on hierarchy, but cannot back this up.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just incase anyone else needs this, the 'Halo News' item I mentioned wasn't a category, it was a custom link in the menu. I assumed that the classes we based on menu hierarchy not page/post structure... I assumed wrong :)